# Magento Most Viewed Products Report empty

Tags: database, products, reports, dashboard

Alright so the issue is that i'm not seeing any records in the dashboard, reports, or database for Most Viewed Products.  I've seen a couple of solutions where there's data in the database but it's not populating the dashboard.  However in my case no data is in the database or the admin area.  The site has been live for a couple of weeks with a lot of traffic so there should be something here.  Any ideas?  Is there a setting where this could have been turned off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We'll need more info than this. possible errors or causes, 3th party modules etc

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Admin -> Reports -> Refresh Statistics`, then select the reports you want to refresh, then hit the submit button.

Once refresh, go back to the report, and select the required to and from dates, then click on the show reports button.

You should see the report as required.

If there is still nothing, the you may need to dig around in the `report_viewed_product_*` tables and see if there is in fact any data there.